# My c-style string is acting very strangely

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I have created a String object, which just contains a char* string; member. I am overloading operator+ by copying the member from my object than the member of the parameter, both into a char * variable. But for some reason I am getting around 16 added giberish characters when I print the result (the casting overload is 100% fine). I have narrowed it down to the               char* sum  = new char[length] that's the issue. I checked the strlen(sum) and it showed up equaling 22, when it is supposed to be 6 letters long. anyone has a clue what the problem may be?

```
String String::operator+(const String& rhs)  
{
    int length = strlen(string) + strlen(rhs.string);
    char* sum = new char[length];
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(string);i++)
        sum[i] = string[i];
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(rhs.string);i++)
        sum[strlen(string) +i] = rhs.string[i];
    String s(sum);



    return s;

}
```

edit: now the gibberish is gone, but I still have = appended to my result, so for example: "1" + "2" + "3" is now "1=2=3". Is this a result of the null terminator interpreted wrong?

edit again: never mind, was being really louzy and set [length+1] = '\0' instead of [length]. Thanks again for the great answers!

Comment: I don't think using `string` as a variable name is a good idea.

Comment: I assume you're doing this for educational purposes? Or is there some other reason not to use `std::string`?

Comment: educational purpose is right, my friend

Comment: @Michael: Why not? It might be a problem if you alias `std::string` into an inappropriate scope, but no-one would do that, would they?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strlen` tells you how many characters there are from the start of the string up to, but not including, the terminating '\0'. When you allocate a new string, you have to leave room for the terminating `\0':

```
char *sum = new char[length + 1];
```

and append a `\0' after you copy the two strings.

Answer (score 7):

You do not allocate memory for the terminating `'\0'` character. You have to allocate `length+1` bytes for the concatenation. Also, you have to set `sum[length] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 7):

You are allocating `length` characters - that's not enough space to store the terminating null. Also, you're not writing a terminating null. C-style strings are null-terminated.

And store the result of `strlen` in local variables. Unless the compiler knows it can safely optimize `strlen` (not guaranteed), the repeated calls will make your function **incredibly** slow.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would locally storing the result of `strlen` make this very slow? I can only think of aliased pointers here, but they don't seem to be a dramatic issue.

Comment: Sorry, that was extremely poor wording on my part. **Not** storing the result makes it very slow. Edited to clarify.